# sharepoint 2010 - dynamically load web part in web part zone using jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, web-parts

i would like to have a link, when clicked loads a web part (for example list view web part) that retains its user config. therefore it needs to be a in a web part zone, personalizable and retain its personalization from previous visits.

my actual scenario is i have an app that has nav/tabs down the left hand side, when each tab is clicked it shows a hidden div to the right with the content relating to the clicked tab.

each div/content has different types of data, some divs will have custom web parts/controls and other will have out of the box ones. These need to be loaded without post backs as there is a lot of content on each div and i would rather not pre-load all in hidden divs. thanks :)

Comment: Welcome!

It would be helpful if you broke this down, showed us the code you are using currently, where you are having an issue, and explained with real world scenarios what you're trying to do. :)

Comment: Hi Brian, i havn't written any code yet. purely at the architecture stage. i don't know where to start on this one. thanks. i could pre-load the whole thing on one page and then swap out the content area with hidden divs. but for performance/load reasons i want to load the divs and respective web parts when requested. hope that makes more sense.

Comment: just want to clarify, its not IN the web part i want to load data.. its the web part itself.

Comment: have a look at this navbar, each content region should have a web part in web part zone that asynch loads when each tab is clicked.

Comment: As far as "web part" goes, are you talking about a div? an iFrame? or something else?

Comment: http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/312_bs/My-Bootstrap-Site-NAVBAR/navbar-examples.html

Comment: sharepoint 2010 webpart in a web part zone. which is in a div

Comment: You might want to mosey on over to the sharepoint site for questions. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ and see what they have to say.